# Classical example of homesickness

Tags: classical-latin, example-request, passage-request

My dictionary translates "homesickness" as *nostalgia* or *desiderium loci natalis*, but the dictionary gives no source or era information.
Both of these are understandable, but I haven't found classical examples of their use.
**Are there examples in classical Latin literature where homesickness is mentioned, using these or other words?**
I would like to know how the Romans would express this.

Homesickness can arise on different time scales.
For example, this is relatively short scale: "I've been travelling for a week, and I really want to get back where I live."
This is much longer scale: "I've lived here for two decades. I wish I could move back to where I spent my childhood summers."
Any time scale is fine for me; I should be able to adapt the ideas to any situation if I just have an attested classical starting point.

Comment: *Nostalgia* seems to be Late Latin at the earliest, from a post-Classical Greek compound, from the attested Classical νόστος "return home" + ἄλγος "suffering". Haven't found any relevant use of the full word in either Latin or Greek.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nostalgia is definitely a modern word.  It was first coined by Johannes Hofer in 1688 in his *Dissertatio Medica de Nostalgia*.  About devising the word, he wrote:

[image]

(from *[Nostalgia: Origins and Ends of an Unenlightened Disease](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=tlmihfXbud8C&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=ovid%20nostalgia&source=bl&ots=kHqKrBDaBy&sig=Y3BBZzZn3qFW9HHFAJ-EiFs0M8U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic9cmB3vfRAhUE2LwKHVwNAGkQ6AEIHDAB#v=snippet&q=dissertatio&f=false)*, by Helmut Illbruck, p. 5)

However, the construction of *desiderium* + gen. of the object longed for + a verb that describes how the longing manifested itself is amply attested to in classical Latin.

Parmeno, a slave, runs into Philotis, a courtesan recently returned to Athens after an unhappy sojourn in Corinth:

> *Edepol, te **desiderium** **Athenarium** arbitror, Philotium, **cepisse** saepe et
>   tu tuom consilium contempisse*
>
> By Pollux, I suppose a longing for Athens often took hold of you, Philotis, and
>   you regretted your decision [to leave]
>
> Terence, *Hecyra* (*The Mother-in-Law*)

In fact, John Barsby (2001) translates this as: I expect you were often homesick …

Cicero, writing to Caelius Rufus in Rome:

> *Mirum me **desiderium** **tenet urbis**, incredibile **meorum** atque in primus
>   **tui**, satietas autem provinciae*
>
> An extraordinary longing for the city (Rome) grips me, more than you
>   would believe, for my family and especially for you, I have had enough
>   of the provinces
>
> Cicero, *Epistulae*, 90 (2.11)

Horace speaking to a bailiff who now works and resides in the country but pines for the excitement of the city:

> *Fornix tibi et uncta popina **incutiunt urbis** **desiderium***
>
> The brothel and greasy cook shop excites in you a longing for the city
>
> Horace, *Epistulae*, 1.14.22

And, of course, Ovid, whose *Tristia* is nothing if not an extended treatise on the soul-destroying nature of homesickness:

> *Roma **domus**que **subit** **desiderium**que **locorum**, quicquid et amissa restat
>   in urbe mei*
>
> Rome, my home, and a longing for its places steals into my thoughts
>   and whatever remains of me in the city I have lost
>
> Ovid, *Tristia*, 3.2.21-22

Answer (score 2):

Ovid, *Metamorphoses* 8.184:

> Daedalus interea Creten longumque perosus
>   exilium **tactusque loci natalis amore**
>   clausus erat pelago.

This bit from Cicero, *Pro Ligario* 3 may count too. *OLD* includes this passage among the attestations for definition 4 of *domus*, 'The country, towm, etc., of one's residence or birth, home; an (inhabited country).'

> Ligarius **domum spectans, ad suos redire cupiens**, nullo se implicari negotio passus est.

Comment: Many thanks! These are excellent examples.